# failed to create symbolic/hard link in volume in docker on windows 7

Tags: docker, docker-machine, ln

I am trying to execute shell script in volume inside docker container on windows 7 but seeing following errors:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/lib/tcl8.5': Protocol error

ln: failed to create hard link 'libpython2.7.so' => 'libpython2.7.so.1.0': Operation not permitted
```

This is the command in shell script which is giving error:

```
root@57856515e02b:/artifacts/test/install/lib# ln -s /usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.5 /artifacts/test/install/lib/
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/artifacts/test/install/lib/tcl8.5': Protocol error
```

I dint see these issues when I run this shell script inside docker container on linux.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
```

Can someone let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you add the shell script? It's hard to get to the bottom of the error without seeing the command causing it.

Comment: I have updated the command and output in shell script which is giving the error. Ran that command in running docker container.

Comment: What docker image are you using? can you also share your docker run command?

Comment: Running this command on the debian:jessie container, running on windows 10 yields no error.

Comment: Any solution for windows 7 platform?

Comment: I am still stuck with this issue, any alternative?